# Transform JSON response with lodash

Tags: lodash

I'm new in lodash (v3.10.1), and having a hard time understanding.
Hope someone can help.

I have an input something like this:

```
{
     {"id":1,"name":"Matthew","company":{"id":1,"name":"abc","industry":{"id":5,"name":"Medical"}}},
     {"id":2,"name":"Mark","company":{"id":1,"name":"abc","industry":{"id":5,"name":"Medical"}}},
     {"id":3,"name":"Luke","company":{"id":1,"name":"abc","industry":{"id":5,"name":"Medical"}}},
     {"id":4,"name":"John","company":{"id":1,"name":"abc","industry":{"id":5,"name":"Medical"}}},
     {"id":5,"name":"Paul","company":{"id":1,"name":"abc","industry":{"id":5,"name":"Medical"}}}
];
```

I would like to output this or close to this:

```
{
     "industries": [
        {
            "industry":{
                "id":5,
                "name":"Medical",
                "companies": [
                    {
                        "company":{
                            "id":1,
                            "name":"abc",
                            "employees": [
                                {"id":1,"name":"Matthew"},
                                {"id":2,"name":"Mark"},
                                {"id":3,"name":"Luke"},
                                {"id":4,"name":"John"},
                                {"id":5,"name":"Paul"}
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something that gets you close to what you want. I structured the output to be an object instead of an array. You don't need the `industries` or `industry` properties in your example output. The output structure looks like this:

```
{
  "industry name": {
    "id": "id of industry",
    "companies": [
      {
        "company name": "name of company",
        "id": "id of company",
        "employees": [
          {
            "id": "id of company",
            "name": "name of employee"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I use the `_.chain` function to wrap the collection with a lodash wrapper object. This enables me to explicitly chain lodash functions.

From there, I use the `_.groupBy` function to group elements of the collection by their industry name. Since I'm chaining, I don't have to pass in the array again to the function. It's implicitly passed via the lodash wrapper. The second argument of the `_.groupBy` is the path to the value I want to group elements by. In this case, it's the path to the industry name: `company.industry.name`. `_.groupBy` returns an object with each employee grouped by their industry (industries are keys for this object).

I then do use `_.transform` to transform each industry object. `_.transform` is essentially `_.reduce` except that the results returned from the `_.transform` function is always an object.

The function passed to the `_.transform` function gets executed against each key/value pair in the object. In the function, I use `_.groupBy` again to group employees by company. Based off the results of `_.groupBy`, I map the values to the final structure I want for each employee object.

I then call the `_.value` function because I want to unwrap the output collection from the lodash wrapper object.

I hope this made sense. If it doesn't, I highly recommend reading [Lo-Dash Essentials](http://search.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/9781784398330). After reading the book, I finally got why lodash is so useful.

```
"use strict";

var _ = require('lodash');

var emps = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "Matthew", "company": { "id": 1, "name": "abc", "industry": { "id": 5, "name": "Medical" } } },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Mark", "company": { "id": 1, "name": "abc", "industry": { "id": 5, "name": "Medical" } } },
  { "id": 3, "name": "Luke", "company": { "id": 1, "name": "abc", "industry": { "id": 5, "name": "Medical" } } },
  { "id": 4, "name": "John", "company": { "id": 1, "name": "abc", "industry": { "id": 5, "name": "Medical" } } },
  { "id": 5, "name": "Paul", "company": { "id": 1, "name": "abc", "industry": { "id": 5, "name": "Medical" } } }
];

var result = _.chain(emps)
  .groupBy("company.industry.name")
  .transform(function(result, employees, industry) {
    result[industry] = {};
    result[industry].id = _.get(employees[0], "company.industry.id");

    result[ industry ][ 'companies' ] = _.map(_.groupBy(employees, "company.name"), function( employees, company ) {
      return {
        company: company,
        id: _.get(employees[ 0 ], 'company.id'),
        employees: _.map(employees, _.partialRight(_.pick, [ 'id', 'name' ]))
      };
    });
    return result;
  })
  .value();
```

Results from your example are as follows:

```
{
  "Medical": {
    "id": 5,
    "companies": [
      {
        "company": "abc",
        "id": 1,
        "employees": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Matthew"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Mark"
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Luke"
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "John"
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Paul"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Sweet! This works and your explanation is awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you ever wanted the exact same structure as in the questions, I solved it using the jsonata library:

```
(
    /* lets flatten it out for ease of accessing the properties*/
    $step1 :=    $ ~> | $ | 
            {
                "employee_id": id,
                "employee_name": name,
                "company_id": company.id,
                "company_name": company.name,
                "industry_id": company.industry.id,
                "industry_name": company.industry.name        
            }, 
            ["company", "id", "name"] |;
    
    /* now the magic begins*/
    $step2 := {
        "industries": 
            [($step1{                
                "industry" & $string(industry_id): ${
                    "id": $distinct(industry_id)@$I,
                    "name": $distinct(industry_name),
                    "companies": [({
                        "company" & $string(company_id): {
                            "id": $distinct(company_id),
                            "name": $distinct(company_name),
                            "employees": [$.{                                
                                    "id": $distinct(employee_id),
                                    "name": $distinct(employee_name)
                                
                            }]
                        }
                    } ~> $each(function($v){ {"company": $v} }))]
                }
                
            } ~> $each(function($v){ {"industry": $v} }))]
        
    };    
)
```

You can see it in action on the live demo site: https://try.jsonata.org/VvW4uTRz_